# Change default "Select Category" text in categories dropdown widget in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

The default dropdown categories widget in WordPress displays the text "Select Category" as a first option by default, is there a simple method to change this text without using a plugin or modifying the core WordPress file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a function like this one in your `functions.php` in the stylesheet directory:

```
function ChangeSelectTitle($cat_args){
$cat_args['show_option_none'] = __('My Category');
return $cat_args;
}
add_filter('widget_categories_dropdown_args', 'ChangeSelectTitle');
```

Where **My Category**  is the new title you want instead of `Select Category`

Comment: Perfect. I always seem to overlook/forget about the functions.php-related solutions and hacks :S